# Taking apart a fuse safely

Tags: fuses

I’m planning to make a Van De Graaf generator, and it requires using only the glass part from a fuse. Is it safe to remove the glass part from a fuse by heating it with a soldering iron or match? I just need a fuse like the smallest fuse shown in this image.

[image: Fuses]

I’ve looked at automotive fuses at a local store like the Littelfuse fuses but the Littelfuse packages always [contain the California state warning about possible exposure to toxic chemicals/metals](https://www.littelfuse.com/about-us/sustainability/california-proposition-65.aspx).

Are there other brands or types of fuses that I can safely take apart to obtain the glass cylinder to make my Van De Graaf generator? And is it best to use a soldering iron or a match to safely take apart the fuse?

Comment: California proposition 65 is on pretty much everything.  I think automotive fuses are plastic, so no glass in them anyway.

Comment: @OskarSkog Prop. 65 had the opposite effect since all companies are slapping it on everything as a cover-all.

Comment: @winny Even the state of California itself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKqWkksewDg

Comment: The fuses may contain lead and/or nickel, or  use some sort of glue that may be toxic if you heat or eat enough of it. Prop 65 warnings are generally meaningless since it is stamped on most everything ("cry wolf" effect). Even water should come with a Prop 65 warning since it is toxic if you consume enough of it (LD50 of 90g/kg). Many glues succumb to heat. Try heating the end-cap with a hot air source and see if that's enough to loosen the end cap.

Comment: @J.A.:  I'd like to know where the glass cylinder from a fuse is supposed to go in a Van de Graaff generator.

Comment: @JRE There are a number of VDG generator designs posted online that use glass cylinder from fuse, as glass and rubber can be one of the combinations of materials that create the static charge, for example [this set of instructions.](http://sites.psu.edu/jessegalvanportfolio/wp-content/uploads/sites/46413/2016/04/InstructionSet.pdf).

Comment: I have used fuses for this exact purpose. I do not recommend using a match, use a soldering iron. I can confirm it works. Prop 65 is extremely conservative. In the levels you'll be dealing with, the health risks are minimal. Just don't breathe in the fumes, use proper ventilation as you would for soldering, and wash your hands afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Older cars used the glass type fuses in a couple of sizes. Also many older electrical devices used smaller ones.

I would use a small grinder or dremel to cut the metal cap corner and the solder to the wire running through - but that wire might break easily though by pulling.

That would seem the easiest option to me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I used to disassemble glass fuses simply by heating the end cap with a mild flame or soldering iron.  This was many years ago but I suspect that modern glass fuses still use a thermoset adhesive.

Certainly no danger in trying.  Just be sure the fuse doesn't contain any of the silica sand found in fuses rated for higher voltage / currents.  In other words, clear fuses like your picture shows.